# Retrieving a contact group's name using the Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm using the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) to get all the contacts of a user under a Google business domain. I was able to list the contacts and get the list of `Person` objects and the `contactGroupId` from the [ContactGroupMembership](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#contactgroupmembership) object. Is there a way to get the name and other details of a user-created group without having to use the Google Contacts API?

Comment: Check this [SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604406/retrieving-information-about-a-contact-with-google-people-api-java)

Comment: @KENdi I had already looked through that. The field list of ContactGroupMembership (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#contactgroupmembership)  only has the contactGroupId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a contact group name by using the newly released contact group endpoints: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups