# Why can't I retrieve emails addresses and phone numbers with Google People API?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I want to retrieve my contacts names, email address and phone numbers using the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/) and I'm using their [Try it!](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#try-it) tool to test the API.

The **names are being retrieved but not the emails addresses and phone numbers**. I think I'm doing everything correctly. I'm properly authenticated with the proper scopes and selected fields.
[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe this is an issue on Google's side?

Comment: Do the connections have to 'enable' sharing those details? Mobile apps or sites using Google+ usually have to prompt for additional information.

Comment: Don't you have to pass an access_token in the request url?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604406/retrieving-information-about-a-contact-with-google-people-api-java). According to the Google People API docs omitting this [`RequestMask`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/RequestMask) field will include all fields but that's not happening. In my case setting the `RequestMask` field to `person.names,person.emailAddresses,person.phoneNumbers` works.

Comment: Excellent find. Thank you for making it possible for me to stop banging my head into the People API wall <3

Comment: You saved me with this! Thank you!

Comment: This was giving me Forest Whitaker eye.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I've being trying to use the google people api with your provided request. But I'm have this error0 { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/…;, "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } My request URL is https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?key=api_key 

Can you help me out with what the problem here is

Comment: The documentation says `RequestMask` is deprecated, use `personFields` instead https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/RequestMask

Answer (score 2):

You have to use people.connections.list to fetch the list of contacts, then loop over them and use people.get in order to fetch each individual contact. In my case I set pageSize to 50 and then I use [people:batchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet) (which supports up to 50 resource names at a time) to fetch the details for those 50 contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear — because it *really* wasn't to me — if you are constructing the `GET` request yourself the query parameter for the request mask is `requestMask.includeField`. The nested JSON is flattened to a keypath. So the complete connection list `GET` request would be something like:

https://content-people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=person.names,person.addresses,person.email_addresses,person.organizations,person.phone_numbers

Answer (score 2):

User's phone numbers and other details will be fetched only if the user has added them to their Google profile.

If you are using [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#try-it) tool and with 'resourceName =  people/me', then :

1. you should be logged in with your Google account and
2. give your consent to allow the google API explorer tool to access logged in user's (in this case your) profile details. [See example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2SeP.png)

After the consent is given by you, it will be able to fetch 'phoneNumbers' and 'addresses' for the logged in user.

If you want to access other user's profile or you are calling the API from any other source then:

1. the user must give permission to your app/website/program to access the requested information from his/her profile
2. you must include 'authorization' KEY in GET REQUEST HEADERS with VALUE "Bearer (OAuth accesstoken of the target user)" to get personal details from the target user's profile.

The OAuth accesstoken can be obtained directly from the user consent response or by exchanging refreshtoken for accesstoken.

Comment: The OP specifically requested information about their contacts email addresses and phone number. You solution is for logged in user profile details

Answer (score 1):

Once you have credentials object saved somewhere. You can retrieve the phone numbers and other details by using following code. You just have to set the RequestMask

```html
#get the credentials

cred_obj = OAuth2Credentials.new_from_json(credentials)
http = httplib2.Http()

#create service

people_service = build(serviceName='people', version='v1', http=cred_obj.authorize(http))

results = people_service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me',
                requestMask_includeField='person.names,person.emailAddresses,person.phoneNumbers',
                                                     pageSize=160)

res = results.execute()
connections = res.get('connections', [])

for person in connections:
    names = person.get('names', [])
    phone_numbers = person.get('phoneNumbers', [])
    if len(names) > 0:
        name = names[0].get('displayName')
    if len(phone_numbers)>0:
        phone_no = phone_numbers[0].get('value')
        print name, phone_no
```