# Google People API get contacts emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-people-api

I need to get contacts emails with Google People API, but can't find a way to do it in docs. Currently I'm making the following request:

```
request.get('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?access_token=tokenHere',
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

And getting the following responce (I pin only the part of it, for example):

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/c1705421824339784415",
  "etag": "328OLZwdaiQ=",
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "type": "CONTACT",
        "id": "17aae01d0ff8b2df",
        "etag": "#328OLZwdaiQ="
      }
    ],
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "17aae01d0ff8b2df"
        }
      },
      "displayName": "testGoogleContact",
      "givenName": "testGoogleContact",
      "displayNameLastFirst": "testGoogleContact"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is under the Google Plus API I think

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper thanks, I was able to get user's profile with request `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=tokenHere`, but I can't find a way to get contacts of user, is it possible with Google Plus API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper thanks again, looks like I already read that guide and I can't find a way to get user's contact's emails there, only currently authenticated user email, anyway, thank you for answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use the Google Plus API: This is what I found on the Google Plus API Documentation page:

> You can get an email address for the authenticated user by using the
>   email scope.
>
> The following JavaScript code example demonstrates how to:
>
> Use Google+ Sign-In to authenticate the user and get a valid OAuth 2.0
>   access token.
>
> Use the token to make an HTTP GET request to the
>
> `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me`
>
> REST endpoint. Parse the response and display the user's email
>   address.

The JSON should like something like this:

```
 {"kind":"plus#person","etag":"\"xw0en60W6-NurXn4VBU-CMjSPEw/mjjYoraGfq3Wi-8Nee4F3k7GYrs\"","emails":[{"value":"**EMAIL**","type":"account"}],"objectType":"person","id":"Person ID","displayName":"FULL NAME","name":{"familyName":"LAST NAME","givenName":"NAME"},"url":"https://plus.google.com/USER","image":{"url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-RTcRn6jTuoI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEpg/Y6cMxfwtbQ4/photo.jpg?sz=50","isDefault":false},"placesLived":[{"value":"CITY","primary":true}],"isPlusUser":true,"verified":false,"cover":{"layout":"banner","coverPhoto":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SybH-BjYW2ft1rzayamGLg_VwW7ocgnQ5cAxH3ROEpODvyaEODpYKW55gmAxCXDUvfKggQ4=s630-fcrop64=1,00002778ffffffff","height":626,"width":940},"coverInfo":{"topImageOffset":0,"leftImageOffset":0}},"result":{"kind":"plus#person","etag":"\"xw0en60W6-NurXn4VBU-CMjSPEw/mjjYoraGfq3Wi-8Nee4F3k7GYrs\"","emails":[{"value":"**EMAIL HERE**","type":"account"}],"objectType":"person","id":"116508277095473789406","displayName":"FULL NAME","name":{"familyName":"LAST NAME","givenName":"NAME"},"url":"https://plus.google.com/USER","image":{"url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-RTcRn6jTuoI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEpg/Y6cMxfwtbQ4/photo.jpg?sz=50","isDefault":false},"placesLived":[{"value":"CITY I LIVE","primary":true}],"isPlusUser":true,"verified":false,"cover":{"layout":"banner","coverPhoto":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SybH-BjYW2ft1rzayamGLg_VwW7ocgnQ5cAxH3ROEpODvyaEODpYKW55gmAxCXDUvfKggQ4=s630-fcrop64=1,00002778ffffffff","height":626,"width":940},"coverInfo":{"topImageOffset":0,"leftImageOffset":0}}}}
```

Source: [Google Plus API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this question: the solution to retrieving the *email addresses of an authorized user's contacts*, what the OP seems to want (not the authorized user's own email address) is at [Why can't I retrieve emails addresses and phone numbers with Google People API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466050/why-cant-i-retrieve-emails-addresses-and-phone-numbers-with-google-people-api/36466702).

**Explanation**: If you look at the section under "Query Parameters" on https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list, you'll see that `requestMask` is a parameter (documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/RequestMask).

It says that you'll need to include the `requestMask` parameter in your query, because you're doing a `people.list` query (i.e. using the `connections` GET endpoint). The `requestMask` parameter basically tells the API what fields to pull: `person.emailAddresses` tells it to pull the peoples' email addresses, `person.emailAddresses,person.names` tells it to pull their email addresses and names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?sortOrder=FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING&fields=connections(emailAddresses%2Cnames)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Try this and it will give you the emails.  Make sure your contacts has emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the profile emails from the Google People API, by making a request to `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me`.

If you want non public emails, you will need to request the `email` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read` scope as specified in https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#profile-scopes