# Will people.get method be affected by Google+ API deprecation?

Tags: google-plus, google-people-api

I'm using the Google People API to get user account info (only for the user who authorized via gmail sign in using the Gmail API) from a Node JS client. I want to make sure that the people.get method I use won't be affected by the shutdown of Google+ and it's APIs.

This is an excerpt from the email that Google sent on 12/20/18 notifying developers of the shutdown:

"Note: If you see calls to people.get, these can be the result of using the Google+ Sign-In feature in your application, which is now fully deprecated and is being shut down. Developers should migrate from the Google+ Sign-In feature to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in authentication system."

As stated above, I am using the People API to call people.get but it's unclear to me whether or not this will be affected by the Google+ deprecation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `people.get` API documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get, then you're fine. This API is *not* impacted by the Google+ API shutdown.

If you're using the `people.get` API documented at https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get, then you will need to migrate to a different API.